# Vuetify v-menu dropdown is shown at incorrect location while using css zoom property

Tags: javascript, html, css, vuejs2, vuetify.js

[image]

As shown in attached picture, v-menu position is at incorrect location while using zoom css property.

Corresponding codepen : https://codepen.io/satishvarada/pen/YzjGNVZ

Similar issues wile using v-autocomplete component too.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data: () => ({
    items: [{
        title: 'Click Me'
      },
      {
        title: 'Click Me'
      },
      {
        title: 'Click Me'
      },
      {
        title: 'Click Me 2'
      },
    ],
  }),
})
```

```css
html {
  zoom: 40%
}
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/vuetify@2.6.13/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-polyfill/dist/polyfill.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuetify@2.6.13/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>


<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <div class="text-center">
      <v-menu offset-y>
        <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
          <v-btn
            color="primary"
            dark
            v-bind="attrs"
            v-on="on"
          >
            Dropdown
          </v-btn>
        </template>
        <v-list>
          <v-list-item v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="index">
            <v-list-item-title>{{ item.title }}</v-list-item-title>
          </v-list-item>
        </v-list>
      </v-menu>
    </div>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to use the `left` prop, so the menu will always be on the left side.

**EDIT-**

Another way would be to attach the menu to its parent element using [attach](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-menu/#props) prop, so the component would know which DOM element it should detach to.

Here is the demo with both props-

**1. With zoom property-**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data: () => ({
    items: [{
        title: 'Click Me'
      },
      {
        title: 'Click Me'
      },
      {
        title: 'Click Me'
      },
      {
        title: 'Click Me 2'
      },
    ],
  }),
})
```

```css
html {
  zoom: 40%
}
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/vuetify@2.6.13/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-polyfill/dist/polyfill.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuetify@2.6.13/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-row>
      <v-col>
        <div class="text-center">
          <div class="mb-2"> Using left prop </div>
          <v-menu offset-y :left="true">
            <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
              <v-btn color="primary" dark v-bind="attrs" v-on="on">
                Dropdown
              </v-btn>
            </template>
            <v-list>
              <v-list-item v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="index">
                <v-list-item-title>{{ item.title }}</v-list-item-title>
              </v-list-item>
            </v-list>
          </v-menu>
        </div>
      </v-col>
      <v-col>
        <div class="text-center" id="parent">
          <div class="mb-2"> Using attach prop </div>
          <v-menu offset-y attach="#parent">
            <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
              <v-btn color="primary" dark v-bind="attrs" v-on="on">
                Dropdown
              </v-btn>
            </template>
            <v-list>
              <v-list-item v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="index">
                <v-list-item-title>{{ item.title }}</v-list-item-title>
              </v-list-item>
            </v-list>
          </v-menu>
        </div>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

**2. Without zoom property-**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data: () => ({
    items: [{
        title: 'Click Me'
      },
      {
        title: 'Click Me'
      },
      {
        title: 'Click Me'
      },
      {
        title: 'Click Me 2'
      },
    ],
  }),
})
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/vuetify@2.6.13/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-polyfill/dist/polyfill.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuetify@2.6.13/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-row>
      <v-col>
        <div class="text-center">
          <div class="mb-2"> Using left prop </div>
          <v-menu offset-y :left="true">
            <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
              <v-btn color="primary" dark v-bind="attrs" v-on="on">
                Dropdown
              </v-btn>
            </template>
            <v-list>
              <v-list-item v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="index">
                <v-list-item-title>{{ item.title }}</v-list-item-title>
              </v-list-item>
            </v-list>
          </v-menu>
        </div>
      </v-col>
      <v-col>
        <div class="text-center" id="parent">
          <div class="mb-2"> Using attach prop </div>
          <v-menu offset-y attach="#parent">
            <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
              <v-btn color="primary" dark v-bind="attrs" v-on="on">
                Dropdown
              </v-btn>
            </template>
            <v-list>
              <v-list-item v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="index">
                <v-list-item-title>{{ item.title }}</v-list-item-title>
              </v-list-item>
            </v-list>
          </v-menu>
        </div>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Comment: great answer! v-data-footer also contains a v-select menu, and it will has the zoom issue, do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Hey, your question is really interesting it got me thinking in one another way for which I am editing the answer and coming back to your question.

Comment: Hey, I think about `v-data-footer`. I can only say if there is a way to customize the footer menu we can try applying the `attach` prop to it.

Comment: thanks! it seems that's the only way TT